# How to display byte array in a picturebox in C++/Cli

Tags: windows, visual-c++, c++-cli, arrays

The user's photo are stored in an SQL table in a binary column.
I retrieve this binary data into a dataset.
How can I display this data as a a photo in a picturebox?

I tried this, but it doesn't work :(

```
array<byte>^ byteBLOBData  =  gcnew array<byte>(200);
    byteBLOBData = (array<byte>^)( dataSet->Tables[ 0 ]->Rows[ 0 ]->ItemArray[ 7 ] );
    System::IO::MemoryStream^ stmBLOBData = gcnew System::IO::MemoryStream(byteBLOBData );
    pictureBox1->Image = Image::FromStream( stmBLOBData );
```

Unfortunately I got an exception :"Parameter is not valid"

Comment: That means that the data in the table is not in a known image format.  Of course we can't guess what format it is either, you'll need to sort that out on your end.  Talk to whomever wrote the code that puts the data in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. In my database the was stored wrong. I corrected it, and now it is working fine. 
Thanks!